# Laravel API routes not working for POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE requests on server

Tags: php, laravel, nginx

I have a Laravel application that works as an API-only backend. The application was running fine on my local machine, but after deploying it to a server and configuring Nginx for reverse proxying, I'm facing an issue where only GET requests are working correctly. All other requests (POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE) are not working.

When I try to send a POST, PUT, PATCH, or DELETE request to my Laravel API routes, the requests coming as GET response(even if the request method is POST), but GET requests are working as expected.

here's my nginx's configuration:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name api.example.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Prefix /;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Authorization, Content-Type';
    }
}
```

Laravel Configuration:

```
Laravel version: 11.x
PHP version: 8.3
The APP_URL and TRUST_PROXIES variables in the .env file are set correctly.
CSRF token validation is disabled for the API routes
```

Comment: So your setup is that you have nginx acting as a proxy to a another server serving your api application through port 8000 ? Are there any redirects set at that end ? (also is there any reason why you don't directly server your PHP app from nginx?)

Comment: @apokryfos yeah im using laravel's php artisan serve, and using there is no other services runing. the reason beause im using proxy, in the future i want to use laravel octane for higher performance. but if you want to show how to serve the application through the nginx itself, im pleased))

Comment: Try using  `php artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0` in case it's getting confused by the proxy source ip

Comment: @apokryfos nope that also didnt work out